# Sorting a list of objects by attribute of type num

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this class:

```
Mark {
  String year;
  String classroomReference;
  String studentReference;
  num? noteValue;
  String? markReference;
  String courseReference;
  String evaluationReference;

  Mark({
    required this.year,
    required this.classroomReference,
    required this.studentReference,
    this.noteValue,
    this.markReference,
    required this.courseReference,
    required this.evaluationReference,
  });
```

and a list of object:`List<Mark> marks`

I would like to know how to sort the list by the `noteValue` attribute. Order to rank students from first to last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `num` class's `compareTo` function:

```
marks.sort((a, b) => b.noteValue.compareTo(a.noteValue))
```